# Perfomance is bad while switching between the pages with jquery mobile

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile

I was facing performance problem while switching between the pages.I went to various forums and added something like faskclick and more.

First time, when i switch to different page, it takes around 3-4 seconds but from second time it is fast e.g. 1 - 1.5 sec. Now, sometimes, click does not work. Out of 5 clicks, only 2-3 clicks works. I am struggling to figure out what went wrong ?

If you can help me out finding why click is not working and how to improve performance when using jquery mobile, it would really be helpful. Following are my code snippets

```
<html>
<!-- head -->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Project</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />

<script src="StyleSheet/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="StyleSheet/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>

<script src="StyleSheet/fastclick.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">

                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slideout = 'none';

            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                new FastClick(document.body);
            }, false);

            $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
                 $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 500
            });

       </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div data-role="page" id="HomePage" class="jqm-demos">
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <a href="#SecondPage">CLick Me to go second page</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="SecondPage" class="jqm-demos">
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <br> <a href="#HomePage">CLick Me to go first page</a>
                <div id="JQM" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c"
                    data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d"
                    data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h3>
                        <span style="float: left;"> JQM is very slow </span> <a
                            href="#JQM_1" class="splitButtonClicked" data-rel="popup"> <span
                            style="float: right;"
                            class="ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r2"></span>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>I sther any way so that page transition should happen just
                        like native applciation when using JQM ? Botton click also also
                        sometimes not responsive.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- content -->

            <!-- footer -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false"
                data-position="fixed">
                <!--class="ui-bar ui-bar-b"-->
                <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"
                    data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="b">left</a>
                <center>
                    <a href="#HomePage" data-role="button" data-icon="home"
                        data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b">Home</a>
                </center>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"
                    data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="b">Right</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't used jQuery Mobile in several versions so this may not apply. But you used to have to have your `data-role="page"` elements as children of the `body` element. Maybe that will help. When I created a JSFiddle from your code it didn't even initialize the pages, when I removed the `#container` element it started initializing: http://jsfiddle.net/Pc8qY/. That JSFiddle works well, so there is something else going on with your bad performance. What are you testing on? Are you using dev tools like chrome's Timeline profiler to find out what's wrong?

Comment: I am testing this in Android 2.3. I am converting these HTML into hative app using Phonegap. i searched in another forums and added some improvement which they discussed for solving performance problem, adding div container is one of them. One more information, i have 100 such pages in a single html file. Is it creating the issue ? When i try with 2 pages, it is bit fast when i have 100 pages and tries to navigate, it bit slow, it takes arround 2-3 seconds for the navigation

Comment: 100 pages in the same file are too many. Divide the pages by category  (each category will get its own HTML file) and load a single category in non-ajax mode.